# How to join two numeric arrays into a single string separated by a colon?

Tags: string, matlab, vector

I have a situation that: I have one vector **A**, say `10000x1`, and another vector **B** `10000x1`, both are numerical arrays with floating point numbers in it. Now I want to write the data into one line of string as below:

```
A(1):B(1) A(2):B(2) ....A(10000):B(10000)
```

Is there an efficient way to do this? Right now, i am just using a for loop, change the floating number to string first, than add the ':', and then concatenate them together. This is very slow. Could anybody help? Thanks a lot.

Comment: please provide some actual numbers as an example. It's ambiguous at the moment. If `A = [3,5,1,...` and `B = [8,9,5,...` then do you want your string to be `'3:8 5:9 1:5 ....'` or `'3 4 5 6 7 8 5 6 7 8 9 1 2 3 4 5 ....'`? If the former the I recommend `sprintf('%d:%d ', [A,B]')`

Comment: A side question before I answer : why donyou want to do that? This will be a pretty long string

Comment: @Dan 3:8 5:9 1:5 ....is correct understanding. But if A is integer vector, B is double vector, how to do that? I tried sprintf('%d:%f ', [A,B]'), but it doesn't work. The output only contains A, without B.

Comment: @BillBokeeyI want to transform my data into a format which LibSVM accepts. Their format is: 1:0.2324 2:0.3232 3:0.4545 .....

Comment: @yzhu I didn't realise you were using column vectors for `A` and `B`. Try this instead: `sprintf('%d:%f ', [A,B])`

Comment: @Dan It is the same thing. For example, if input is```A = 1:10
B = randn(1,10)
sprintf('%d:%f ',[A,B])```. My output is ```1:2 3:4 5:6 7:8 9:10 6.088942e-01:8.072232e-01 4.285545e-01:8.931010e-01 4.249390e-01:4.236594e-01 6.304087e-01:1.888050e-01 4.633747e-01:9.932405e-01```. It first print out A, then B. They are not interleaved together.

Comment: @yzhu - that's because you just switched back to row vectors! Your `A` in your question is `10000`-by-`1` but now you're using a `1`-by-`10`. One of those needs transposing... if you want to be safe, use the `(:)` trick like thewaywewalk suggests to force the vector to be a columns vector so `sprintf('%d:%f ', [A(:),B(:)]')`

Comment: Thanks for your help @Dan . Rijul's solution below solved the problem, still the dimension thing. I upvote your answers as well. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For dimension `nx1` (Column Matrix)

```
tic
A=rand(10000,1);
B=rand(10000,1);

finalString=sprintf(' %f:%f',[A.'; B.']);
finalString(1)=[];
toc
```

> Elapsed time is 0.036697 seconds.

For dimension `1xn` (Row Matrix)

```
tic
A=rand(1,10000);
B=rand(1,10000);

finalString=sprintf(' %f:%f',[A; B]);
finalString(1)=[];
toc
```

> Elapsed time is 0.036879 seconds.

Value Type

> %f --> Floating-point number(Fixed-point notation)
>
> %d --> Integer, signed(Base 10)

For more value types http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sprintf.html has a table for conversion characters to format numeric and character data as text or you can search `sprintf` in matlab help.

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply. But how about when A is an integer vector, like from 1 to N. I use finalString=sprintf(' %d:%f',A,B); but the output is:                                       1:2.00000 3:4.00000 .....               it seems that it only output A, no B shows up. I was wondering why this is the case.

Comment: Use it like this `finalString=sprintf(' %d:%f',[A;B]);`.

Comment: @yzhu this actually doesn't work as stated in the question because it vertically concatenates column vectors. If it worked for you it's because your `A` and `B` were actually row vectors (unlike what this answer uses and unlike what your question specifies)

Answer (score 1):

This should do it relatively quickly. I included a tic-toc to provide a reference execution time if someone provides an alternative implementation.

```
tic
a=rand(10000,1);
b=rand(10000,1);

c=zeros(20000,1);
c(1:2:end)=a;
c(2:2:end)=b;

c_string=mat2str(c);
idx=find(c_string==';');
c_string(idx(1:2:end))=':';
c_string(idx(2:2:end))=' ';
toc
%Elapsed time is 0.365694 seconds.
```